# Display the highest result of each group with relevance data?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have 4 tables like this :

- "Student" with fields ID, FullName, Gender, ClassID ( "ID" of "Class" ) ....
- "Class" with fields ID, ClassName
- "Subject" with fields ID, SubjectName
- "Points" with fields ID, StudentID ( "ID" of "Student" ), SubjectID ( "ID of Subject" ), ExamPoint

The average exam point of a student, is calculated by adding all the point, then divide this result by the number of subjects. If John has Maths 8 and English 4 and Literature 6 then his average exam point is (8+4+6)/3=6. If Mary has Maths 10 and English 5 then her average exam point is (10+5)/2=7.5

I'm about selecting the person who has the highest average exam point in each class then display their name, their class name and their average exam points. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try these 2 queries. The first is a view that gives you the average exam scores for each student.

V_AveragesPoints

```
SELECT  s.FullName, c.ClassName, AVG(p.ExamPoint) AS AvgPoints
FROM    Points p
INNER   JOIN Student s
        ON p.StudentID = s.ID
INNER   JOIN Class c
        ON s.ClassID = c.ID
GROUP   BY s.FullName, c.ClassName
```

The second gives you a view of the highest averages scores for each class.

```
SELECT  FullName, ClassName, AvgPoints
FROM    V_AveragePoints ap1
WHERE   AvgPoints = (SELECT MAX(AvgPoints) FROM V_AveragePoints WHERE ClassName = ap1.ClassName)
```

I wrote these using standard T-SQL so they should work in MS Access, although I haven't verified them using MS Access yet.  They work fine in SQL Server, but let me know.